# setup Drupal with Docker: clone repositories via deploy token

Tags: 7

I am quite new working with docker. I tried to set up drupal via docker and docker-compose.
So far i got a running instance and installed drupal via the installation script.

No i want to clone repositoires via the Dockerfile, which is a drupal module. So after cloning and rebuilding the module should appear in the admin/modzles page)

So i edited my `Dockerfile` so it looks like this (the last few lines).

```
FROM drupal:7-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        git \
        mysql-client \
        vim \
        wget

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
        php composer-setup.php && \
        mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
        php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

RUN wget -O drush.phar https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/releases/download/0.4.2/drush.phar && \
        chmod +x drush.phar && \
        mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush

RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/*

COPY apache-drupal.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

WORKDIR /app/web/sites/all/modules
RUN git clone -b <branch> --single-branch \
      https://<deploytoken>:<pw>@<gitlab-address>/<path-to-git-rep>.git \

WORKDIR /app
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.2
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <pswd>
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
  drupal:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    restart: always
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Then i used docker-compose build and docker-compose up. It looks like the repository gets cloned and the latest images is used (no errors) but the repository is not in the folder. What did i do wrong?

Comment: You ssh'd in and verified no files were there? Did you evaluate standing solutions like Docker4Drupal first? Might save you a ton of time trying to debug Docker if you are new to it.

Comment: Drupal itself is working fine. I connected to the site and installed drupal with the installation script. But i cant get the GitLab repository to appear. It is a drupal module, so after rebuilding the image is should appear under admin/modules.

Comment: Hmm, i am just seeing that i am using a bind mount and not a volume. I am not so sure about the differences and usages of the two.

Comment: It’s possible there was an error? Bash in and see if you can run the command directly. Anyhow it sounds like a question more focused on Docker.

Answer (score 1):

The way I handle this is creating a gitlab auth.json file and with your token and using a volume mount to put it into the container.

```
volumes:
  - /Users/${USER}/.composer/auth.json:/home/wodby/.composer/auth.json # composer auth
```

In some instances I've wanted my ssh keys in there as well for certain operations, but shouldn't be needed for a pull off gitlab. This is just as easy.

```
volumes:
- /Users/${USER}/.ssh/id_rsa:/home/wodby/.ssh/id_rsa # ssh
```

Comment: This is exactly what I do as well. This would be required for private repositories especially if you use composer or other tools inside the container.

Comment: Ah, i see. I will try that out. Thanks!

Comment: I've also seen people using the token in a url like prefix://key:token@gitlab.com/repo.git but i have found this easiest.

Comment: @Xyarvius If I was able to answer you question, would you accept my answer?